# Context menu in rqt_bag won't appear

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running rqt_bag version 0.2.14 in ROS Groovy, I was trying to right-click the timeline to enable topic publishing, but the menu wouldn't appear. The menu WOULD appear in rxbag. In rqt_bag, however, right-clicks and middle-clicks didn't even seem to dispatch events. The strange part is that on another machine with a different graphics driver, rqt_bag works as expected.

- rqt_bag 0.2.14
- ROS Groovy
- Xubuntu 12.04
- Nvidia CUDA display drivers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59800/context-menu-in-rqt_bag-won%27t-appear/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The world is broken, restart your computer, and it will work again.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0